# Select a value based on the aggregate value of another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a dataset (query in this case) that kind of looks like this:

```
ZipCode Territory       Date
----------------------------------
12345   Unknown         9/30/2015
12345   Unknown         9/25/2015
12345   Istanbul        9/20/2015
12345   Istanbul        9/10/2015
12345   Unknown         9/5/2015
12345   Istanbul        8/31/2015
12345   Istanbul        8/21/2015
12345   Unknown         8/16/2015
12345   Constantinople  8/11/2015
12345   Constantinople  8/1/2015
12345   Constantinople  7/22/2015
12345   Constantinople  7/12/2015
```

I'd like to return the max date and **KNOWN** territory name for each zip code (one row per zipcode). The end result I would expect from the previous query would turn into this:

```
ZipCode Territory   Date
----------------------------------
12345   Istanbul    9/20/2015
```

My current best efforts only got me here:

```
ZipCode Territory       Date
---------------------------------
12345   Istanbul        9/20/2015
12345   Constantinople  8/11/2015
```

Help! This is a huge gap in my SQL writing abilities.

Comment: `SELECT  TOP 1` then your query you currently have looks like it would work

Comment: You may have two territories qualifying for the max date. What do you want to do then?

Comment: You say _...return the max date and territory name **for each zip code (one row per zipcode)**_... but your expected output contains just one row. Could you correct your question or explain better?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I'm processing all these comments and answers.

Comment: I added an important missing detail, there's "unknown" records in the dataset. "Unknown" in the territory column, not to be confused with NULL. So I can't just take the max date and join on date and zipcode, because it has to be a **known** territory name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two queries.

The first to retrieve the max date.

```
SELECT Zipcode, Max([Date]) AS MaxDate FROM <TableName> Group BY Zipcode
```

Let's save this query as qryMaxDateForZipCode

The second to query the territory for that date.

```
SELECT ZipCode, Territory FROM qryMaxDateForZipCode 
INNER JOIN <TableName> ON qryMaxDateForZipCode.MaxDate = <TableName>.[Date]
```

However you may have two territories qualifying for the max date. What do you want to do then?

Comment: Thank you E Mett, while seemingly simple, this was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a greatest-n-per-group question. Group your data by zip code to grab the latest date per zip code. Then match the zip code-latest date pairs with your data:

```sql
SELECT YourTable.* 
FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ZipCode, MAX(Date) AS Date_Max
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Territory <> 'Unknown'
    GROUP BY ZipCode
) AS TempGroup ON
        YourTable.ZipCode = TempGroup.ZipCode 
    AND YourTable.Date = TempGroup.Date_Max
```

Result (tested in MS-Access 2007):

```
ZipCode Territory   Date
----------------------------------
12345   Istanbul    9/20/2015
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Salman A, but Istanbul and Constantinople have the same zip code and I'm looking for the max date and last known territory name for each zip code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help (?):

```
Select ZipCode, MAX(Territory), Max([Date]) AS [Date]
Group By ZipCode
```